# How to convert Xcode 6.1.1 swift code to Xcode 6.4 Swift code?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

Actually, I have implemented the project in Xcode 6.1.1 and Now I want to run the same code on Xcode 6.4 but it's giving me errors as follows :

> 1. 'AnyObject' is not convertible to 'myObject'; did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast?
> 2. 'countElements' has been renamed to count

And many more.

Is there any provision to remove above errors automatically? There are 700+ errors after opening the code in Xcode 6.4. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try "Edit -> Convert -> To Latest Swift Syntax ..." ?

Comment: If that doesn't work, you really need to post code.

Comment: @Martin R, I tried 'Convert' option but bad luck. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

When you've gone to 6.4, you've also upgraded Swift to 1.2. Swift 1.2 uses as! to represent forced conversions. The statement will fail if you downcast to an invalid type.

It's simple though .. you just have to use as! instead of as. One of my apps did not work properly with the conversion tool so I did have to go through and update them manually. It's a pain, but it's a one-off and shouldn't take you more than an hour.